# Uploading large amount of content in to a content component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I need to publish out a large XML file (~8MB = ~28,000 lines) from Tridion (2011 SP1 HR1) on to the web sever(s).

I have done this in the past with similar sized XML documents by uploading the XML file in to a Multimedia Component in Tridion and then having a simple Component Template to render the contents of the file at publish time.  However, in the Tridion implementation in which I am working there is already a mechanism for publishing out content to the site using a very simple 'Code' Content (not Multimedia) Component which has a single plain text field for the 'code'.

The problem that I am having is that the browser becomes unresponsive/crashes when I try to paste such a large amount of content in to the 'Code' Component.  Does anyone know of a way (either in the browser or in Tridion) to make this possible?  I do have the option of adding a Component Template to process this as a Multimedia Component, but I would be reluctant to do this if I could get the existing mechanism working.

I have tried this in IE, Chrome and Firefox.  I have also tried uploading this using WebDav without success too.  We have already increased the HTTP Upload size on the server to 0.5GB to accommodate large binary files.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is the WCF size restrictions in the CoreService configuration.

These are set in the Web.Config of the CME, under (by default): C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot

Comment: Thanks Nuno. Apologies for the delay getting back, I've only just seen your answer.  The problem is actually when we paste the code in to the plain text field, rather than when we try to save the Component.  I suspect that this is a browser issue.  We implemented this using a Multimedia Component in the end.